# Making part of the page(audio streamer) not post-back

Tags: php, html, web-applications

Basically, I have a webpage that will have a streaming music player/radio.

Right now, whenever something is done that initiates a postback, the music is also cut.

I think that the old way of doing it was to create a simple pop-up window of the player and from there, the music would play as long as it is needed, but is there any better - modern - way of archieving what I am after?

The page is written in PHP and the music player will be most likely done with HTML5, althought it is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is not so much you can do here.

There is like 3 or 4 options to go:

1) Old school popup's.
2) Iframe based player (usually at the top or bottom of page).
3) Convert website to use Ajax for all that is reloading page.
4) Use flash (definitely not an valid option, but it is an option).

Personally i would go with option 2 for faster implementation and option 3 for sake of modern days and user experience. But it all depends ofc on the website you are building.

Good luck.

Comment: It is basically a small news/blog site of an online community. But thanks, I will look into AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could go fully-blown scripting with [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), and fallback (non-JavaScript) to targeting your form post to a hidden iframe element.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think to do that is to handle your postbacks with AJAX. That way there's never a page refresh when posting data. You can handle the data send and response through javascript, leaving the page (and the player) intact.